# Add constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, cocoa

I have a collectionview and other views inside a scrollview. I need to add constraint programmatically to make sure it works on all devices.

CollectionView/Gallery is inside the UIScrollView. It works before the constraint.

I am using the code below to stick the collectionview to the right but I am getting error
terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:

```
//constraint
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomSpaceConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.galleryView
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                            toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                        multiplier:1.0
                                                                          constant:0.0];
[self.galleryView addConstraint:bottomSpaceConstraint];
```

Comment: What is the relationship between galleryView and self.scrollView? Which is the subview, and has it been added as such by the time this code is run?

Comment: CollectionView/Gallery is inside the UIScrollView.

Comment: In that case, you have to add the constraint to the `scrollView`, not the `galleryView`. As an aside, I might be inclined to call the constraint variable `rightSpaceConstraint`, to make it clear its the right constraint, not the bottom constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Constraints other than height and width must be added to the containing view or highest in the hierarchy.

You might find that scroll views don't make it easy or clear how to set up constraints for the items inside.

In that case, you either do the old school thing for scroll view content or you create an intermediate view inside the scroll view document view.

Scroll views are tricky because they have a clip view that determines how much of the document view is visible.

Comment: What is the old school way of doing it? If else?

Comment: Not using constraints inside the scrollview. It's ok to add them to items of the collection view to size them, but sometimes constraints and scrollviews are a pita. (at least on the desktop they certainly are)

Comment: I wouldn't be inclined to give up on constraints on scroll views, but just remember that constraints between a scroll view and its subviews dictate the `contentSize` of the scroll view, not its `frame`. But constraints with scroll views are a wonderful way to retire the complicated "old school" code to manually determine the `contentSize` of the scroll view. Just add the subviews and their constraints to the scroll view, and the `contentSize` will be calculated automatically for you.

Comment: I sure hope so. It hasn't always been that sweet with the NS variety of scrollviews. or is it???

Comment: For `UIScrollView` it's quite logical (once you realize that the subview's constraints dictate the contentSize) and auto layout can really simplify the process. With `NSScrollView` it is even more logical, because you're adding subviews to the `documentView`, so there's no confusion between the constraints between `documentsView` and its subviews (i.e. the logical equivalent to `contentSize` in `UIScrollView`) and the constraints on the `NSScrollView` itself.